# Unable to see LDAP references after adding them but still able to ldapsearch them

Tags: openldap

I have set up two OpenLDAP servers on my network and am trying to enable authentication through LDAP.  I am able to login to my servers if users are authenticated on the local LDAP server.  However, after I add a reference object to the other server I can't see the object through phpldapadmin. Here's what I am adding with ldapadd.

```
dn: uid=server2,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: referral
objectClass: extensibleObject
cn: server2
ref: ldap://192.168.4.105/ou=People,dc=server2,dc=example,dc=com
```

It successfully adds but I am unable to see it through phpldapadmin.  I can view it through ldapsearch this is what I get.

```
$ ldapsearch -h 192.168.4.106 -x -b "uid=server2,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <uid=server2,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 10 Referral
matchedDN: uid=server2,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
ref: ldap://192.168.4.106/ou=People,dc=server2,dc=example,dc=com??sub
```

The fact that I can't see the objects and that they don't give me access to the other server is driving me nuts.  I have nss_ldap and pam_ldap installed as well as the phpldapadmin module. I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on both servers. This is my slapd.conf for my client.

```
# See slapd.conf(5) for details on configuration options.
# This file should NOT be world readable.
#
include         /usr/share/slapd/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /usr/share/slapd/etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /usr/share/slapd/etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /usr/share/slapd/etc/openldap/schema/corba.schema
include         /usr/share/slapd/etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
include         /usr/share/slapd/etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema

allow bind_v2
# Define global ACLs to disable default read access.

# Do not enable referrals until AFTER you have a working directory
# service AND an understanding of referrals.
referral        ldap://server2.example.com:389

pidfile         /usr/share/slapd/var/run/slapd.pid
argsfile        /usr/share/slapd/var/run/slapd.args

# Load dynamic backend modules:
# modulepath     /usr/local/libexec/openldap
moduleload    back_bdb.la
# moduleload    back_hdb.la
moduleload    back_ldap.la
# Sample security restrictions
#       Require integrity protection (prevent hijacking)
#       Require 112-bit (3DES or better) encryption for updates
#       Require 63-bit encryption for simple bind
# security ssf=1 update_ssf=112 simple_bind=64

overlay                    chain
chain-max-depth 1 #allows 1 referral hop 
chain-uri                  "ldap://192.168.4.106"
chain-rebind-as-user       yes
chain-idassert-bind        bindmethod="simple"
                           binddn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
                           credentials="{SSHA}****"
                           mode="self"
chain-tls                  start
chain-idassert-authzFrom   "*"
chain-return-error         TRUE

# Sample access control policy:
#       Root DSE: allow anyone to read it
#       Subschema (sub)entry DSE: allow anyone to read it
#       Other DSEs:
#               Allow self write access
#               Allow authenticated users read access
#               Allow anonymous users to authenticate
#       Directives needed to implement policy:
# access to dn.base="" by * read
# access to dn.base="cn=Subschema" by * read
# access to *
#       by self write
#       by users read
#       by anonymous auth
#
# if no access controls are present, the default policy
# allows anyone and everyone to read anything but restricts
# updates to rootdn.  (e.g., "access to * by * read")
#
# rootdn can always read and write EVERYTHING!

#######################################################################
# BDB database definitions
#######################################################################

database        bdb
suffix          "dc=server2,dc=example,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=admin,dc=server2,dc=example,dc=com"
# Cleartext passwords, especially for the rootdn, should
# be avoid.  See slappasswd(9) and slapd.conf(5) for details.
# Use of strong authentication encouraged.
rootpw          {SSHA}*********
defaultaccess   none

# The database directory MUST exist prior to running slapd AND 
# should only be accessible by the slapd and slap tools.
# Mode 700 recommended.
directory       /usr/local/var/openldap-data
# Indices to maintain
index   objectClass     eq
```

I would be really grateful if someone could point me in the direction of my problem.  I'm not sure if this is related but I am unable to view my OpenLDAP server through Apache Directory Studio but I can see it through phpldapadmin.

ldap.conf

```
host 192.168.4.105
base dc=server2,dc=example,dc=com
uri ldap://192.168.4.105
ldap_version 3
rootbinddn cn=admin,dc=server2,dc=example,dc=com
rootpw {SSHA}blah
scope sub
timelimit 5
bind_timelimit 5
pam_filter objectclass=posixAccount
pam_login_attribute uid
pam_member_attribute memberuid
pam_password exop
nss_base_passwd         ou=People,dc=server2,dc=example,dc=com?sub
nss_base_shadow         ou=People,dc=server2,dc=example,dc=com?sub
nss_base_group          ou=Group,dc=server2,dc=example,dc=com?sub
nss_base_hosts          ou=Hosts,dc=server2,dc=example,dc=com?sub
nss_initgroups_ignoreusers backup,bin,daemon,games,gnats,irc,landscape,libuuid,list,lp,mail,man,messagebus,news,nslcd,openldap,proxy,root,sshd,statd,sync,sys,syslog,uucp,whoopsie,www-data
```

Comment: Don't you have to configure something at the client to make it automatically chase referrals?

Comment: I've added the chain overlay to slapd.conf of client to get the automatic referral chase but I still cannot get auto referral. The invisible objects will return a referral for a proper search but not the object itself.  I'm trying to do an authentication from the LDAP with success from the LDAP directory pointed to via ldap.conf but authentication hangs till timeout for any user referred to on the other LDAP directory.

Comment: Which version of OpenLDAP are you using? If it's the userbooster.de one, you need the latest download. They fixed a chain overlay bug for me last year. It was present in OpenLDAP 2.4.34.

Comment: I'm using OpenLDAP 2.4.31.  I'll try upgrading to the latest version and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: I've upgraded to OpenLDAP 2.4.38.  The strangest thing happened I was trying to see if the SSL or TSL certificate or authentication was the problem and I added a referral that showed up in phpLDAPadmin and I was able to do an ldapsearch through it and get the correct response. My problem might have something to do with my TSL permissions. I've since lost the configuration that made it tick. I've reposted my slapd and ldap configs.

Comment: I can't check your configuration till Monday. I'm sure the Userbooster guys contribute their fixes back to the OpenLDAP project but it would be worthwhile checking the release notes to ensure the bug fix is in there. It was actually something deep in the connection pooling.